# Ionic2: iOS app crashes when record audio and play again using cordova-plugin-media

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, media

I am developing Media Player for both android and iPhone using ionic platform.

Player having the record audio and play functionality.

I completed with code using this link :
**https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media** .

The ios app is getting crash when I record audio, save it in local storage and play on player. It is working fine in many cases.

I have debug the code and found crash log and console on XCode IDE. Following is the cause of crashing :

**exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: nan**

This may be a plugin issue.
I am stuck on this. If any Idea about why this is causing random crash, please share.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Searched for too long for this simple answer after it was working on Andriod, and I finally tested on iOS

```
import {normalizeURL} from 'ionic-angular';

MediaSource = document.createElement("audio");
MediaSource.src = normalizeURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + file.fullPath);
```

Hope this helps.